# Pay attention to + noun

Tags: vocabulary

Is it okay to say "I PAY ATTENTION TO the house" in the sense I watch it or look after it? Because I am afraid it is a lexical misuse

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that sentence—aside from the fact that it's slightly nonidiomatic. Even as you say, people would more normally say *I look after the house.* But *I pay attention to my teachers* would be perfectly normal. Are you asking about your *specific* sentence or the construction in general?

Comment: To me "I pay attention to the house" would mean something like... over time I carry out maintenance (e.g. plumbing work) when it needs to be done, I notice if things look unusual (a birds' nest in the roof or something like that) and take action about that, etc.

What do you mean by 'watch' or 'look after' a house? Is it your house? Is this a short-term thing or on an ongoing basis that you "always" watch/look after it?

Comment: I think you really mean: take care of

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatically, to ***pay attention to the house*** would mean to watch it carefully - as in *literally* keep an eye on it. For example, if someone was trying to get you to notice some subtle pattern in the way lights changed on a house, they might tell you to pay attention to it. If you were watching a video where something interesting happened to a house in the background, while your attention is normally drawn to something in the foreground, someone might tell you to pay attention to the house.

On the other hand, to ***watch the house*** could mean that, or it could mean a more figurative sense, as could ***keep an eye on the house***. In those cases, it might mean making sure that nothing has happened to the house, letting someone know if it gets burgled, and if it's over a longer period of time probably going in every so often to air it out and make sure there's no damp or mould appearing. I wouldn't expect someone to use *pay attention to the house* to give those meanings.

To ***give attention to the house*** wouldn't be a commonly used phrase, but it would, I think, be understood to mean actively doing things to keep it in a good condition, as would ***maintain the house***. *Give attention* could also be used to mean actively upgrading the house, but I wouldn't encourage anyone to use it for anything. *Maintain*, on the other hand, is a completely natural and commonly used term.